# How do I find intersection of value lists in a txt file RDD with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

I am learning spark and want to work on the intersection of all values in the file

The format of the file looks like the following:

```
a
1, 2, 3, 0, ...

b
0, 5, 20, 3, ...

c
0, 7, 9, 10, 2, 20, ...

d
empty

e
empty
```

I tried doing the following:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile('data.txt')
rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split('\t')).map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])).map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1].split('\n,'))))
ab = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1]))).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (set(x[0]))).map(lambda x: (x[0], list(set(x[1]))))
```

And I now have the data in the following format as key-value pairs.

```
[('a', [1, 2, 3, 0, ...]), ('b', [0, 5, 20, 3,...]), ('c', [0, 7, 9, 10, 2, 20, ...]), ...]
```

I need to find the intersection of each value and other values in the data and attach the keys where the length of the intersection if `>= 2`.

Like:

```
[key, [list of keys in the entire data whose length of intersections with the current key is >=2]]
```

For example, the values of key `a` has intersection `[0, 3]` with values of key `b`. values of Key `a` also has intersection `[0, 2]` with values of key `b`. Similarly, for key `b`, same thing should happen in the case of `a` and `b`. Then `b` and `c` have intersection `[0, 20]`. Finally, `d` will be assigned `e` and vice versa because both are empty.

Sample output:

```
[('a', [b, c]), ('b', [a, c]), ('c', [a, b]), ('d', [e]), ('e', [d])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you input RDD is something like:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    ('a', [1, 2, 3, 0]), ('b', [0, 5, 20, 3]),
    ('c', [0, 7, 9, 10, 2, 20]), ('d', []), ('e', []),
])
```

In order to check values intersections between all combinations of keys you need to apply cartesian product on the RDD, then filter values where there is intersection:

```
from operator import add

def lists_intersect(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) == len(l2) == 0:  # both empty
        return True
    if len(set(l1).intersection(l2)) >= 2:  # have 2 or more same elements
        return True
    return False


result = rdd.cartesian(rdd) \
    .filter(lambda x: x[0][0] != x[1][0] and lists_intersect(x[0][1], x[1][1])) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], [x[1][0]])) \
    .reduceByKey(add)

result.collect()
# [('a', ['b', 'c']), ('d', ['e']), ('c', ['a', 'b']), ('e', ['d']), ('b', ['a', 'c'])]
```

---

Another way by using join instead of cartesian product:

```
# add index to the original rdd
rdd = rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))

# generates another rdd that contains pairs of row indices to check
# combinations of all rows except the row itself 
indices = range(rdd.count())
indices_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    (i, j) for i in indices for j in indices if i != j
])

result = indices_rdd.join(rdd) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[1][0], (x[0], x[1][1]))) \
    .join(rdd) \
    .filter(lambda x: lists_intersect(x[1][0][1][1], x[1][1][1])) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[1][0][1][0], [x[1][1][0]])) \
    .reduceByKey(add)
```

Comment: This seems to work on very small data (at least, I tried with just 10 rows with maximum value list length of 9 and it worked ). I have about 30K key-value pairs with varying value list lengths (some values have up to 90 list lengths) and it's taking forever to run. doing 'result.take(3)'  took more than 70 minutes to run. Any idea on how to make it better? perhaps should stop adding the keys if 10 keys are already added

Comment: @Craving_gold the problem with this approach is that you need to check all combinations so can't avoid the cartesian product. With 30K items, the Cartesian product will produce 900M items which makes it inefficient. The size of array values also causes bad performance when checking intersection. and this is something spark isn't good at in general. I added another way using joins instead of cartesian that you may try.